# Pandas finding a single value with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple question but for some reason I could not figure it out.  I have this df:

```
Name1   Name2  Value1  Value2 
x       z      1       4
y       y      2       5
z       x      3       6
```

My objective is to pull out the single value that either in columns Value1 or Value2 that matches both Name1 and Name2.  For example, I want to get:

v: the value in Value1 where Name1 = x and Name2 = z, then v = 1

w: the value in Value2 where Name1 = z and Name2 = x, then w = 6

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @pault:  I forgot to add that. I usually use np.where() statements but it only works for the whole column.  I got the answer from the help below now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index:

```
df = df.set_index(['Name1', 'Name2'])
```

and then use loc:

```
df.loc[('x', 'z'), 'Value1']
Out: 1

df.loc[('z', 'x'), 'Value2']
Out: 6
```

Comment: is there a way we can get 0 if the value we're looking for is not in the df instead of getting an error?  For example, if I apply df.loc[('a', 'a'), 'Value1'], I would get 0 since 'a' can't be found.

Comment: I think best way to handle that with a try: except KeyError: block.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `query`

```
df.query("Name1=='x' & Name2=='z'").Value1[0]
Out[792]: 1
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the query function.  The only problem that I might encounter with this is that I have to define the position for Value1[ ] and Value2[ ] since my df doesn't always stay in the same order :)